# Reshaping Arrays In Python

Tags: python, numpy

Why flatten() is slower than ravel() function in reshaping arrays in python?

```
x = np.arange(1000000)
x.shape = 100, 100, 100
%timeit x.flatten() 
%timeit x.ravel()
```

NumPy offers many functions and some of them can produce same results
I think it depends on being Inplace and not.

Comment: There aren't many `numpy` functions or methods that work in-place.  But there is an important distinction between a `view` and `copy`.  Operations that return views are faster.  `ravel` is one; it is essentially a `reshape`.  But sometimes even those have to return copies.  Don't skip the official `numpy` docs, especially the beginners and essentials parts.  And then keep the reference section handy for continual reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flatten` always makes a copy. `ravel` makes a view if it can. Copying takes time.